# Creating a hash of hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, hash-of-hashes

I have a hash: `hash1`

```
hash1 = Hash.new
```

I have another hash: `hash2`

```
hash2 = Hash.new
```

I added the following key-value pair in it:

```
hash2.store("k1","v1")
hash2.store("k2","v2")
hash2.store("k3",["v3","v4"])
```

Now, I want to have `"key1"` in `hash1` which will be associated with `"k1", "k2", "k3"` of `hash2`.

I want something of this sort:

```
{"key1"=>{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"v2", "k3"=>["v3", "v4"]}}
```

How do I associate hash1 and hash2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes do then as below :

```
hash1 = Hash.new

hash2 = Hash.new

hash2.store("k1","v1")
hash2.store("k2","v2")
hash2.store("k3",["v3","v4"])
hash1['key1']= hash2

p hash1
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
hash1['key1'] = hash2
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply define a key in your new hash and as a value you just pass in the hash you created earlier:

```
h2 = {k1: "v1", k2: "v2", k3: ["v3","v4"]}
h1 = {key1: h2}
# => {:key1=>{:k1=>"v1", :k2=>"v2", :k3=>["v3", "v4"]}}
```

Or if you prefer to do it via store method, just pass in the `h2` as an argument:

```
h1["key1"] = h2
```